# How do I tell what version of .net i am compiling with, and how would I change it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010 Premium. I am compiling and running an application locally. When i upload it a hosted server, I'm not seeing the results I am expecting. I *think* this might be cause my the host not having the same version of .net I have. then are on .Net 2.

How can I tell what version of .Net I am compiling against?
How can I change that version to another (in this case .Net 2)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each project, look in the project properties screen, Application Tab, there is a drop down labeled Target Framework...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Solution Properties from [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) extension.
It allows you to edit Target Framework, Reference Paths and other settings for all projects from one place (instead of going to properties screen of each project separately):

[image]